# ASP.NET MVC 3 Razor views onclick encoding

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to get my checkbox to submit the form it is in using the below code:

@Html.CheckBox("Completed", new { onclick = "$(this).parent('form:first').submit();" })

It keeps rendering the ' around 'form:first' as html encode values though. Any ideas how to fix this?

Thanks

Nick

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not just wire it up with a jquery click event??

```
@Html.CheckBox("Completed", new { id = "myButtonID" })
```

then in your js code...

```
$(function(){

  $("#myButtonID").click(function(){
      //submit the form here
  });

});
```